# Parse Rest api in json format without an array name in recyclerview

Tags: android, json, rest, android-recyclerview, httpurlconnection

In my app I have implemented recyclerview. this recyclerview will be populated with json data. this json data will come from rest api. Now I am trying to fetch this data using HttpUrlConnection. So far I have implmented this code by reading some of the article on website. But I am not getting any data in recyclerview, so on as response on logcat. I have read similar post on Stackoverflow. But nothing could solve my problem. Here is my json response from api.

**Api Response**

```
[
{
"_id": "595bdcf32c67a3f9ee6c2a21",
"dn": "ferwetrert",
"whenChanged": "20170704065349.0Z",
"name": "Student",
"mail": "student@mail.com",
"updated_at": "2017-07-04T18:22:43.624Z"
 },
{ 
"_id": "595bdcf32c67a3f9ee6c2a25",
"dn": "CN=Accounting,OU=users,OU=bluERP,OU=companies,DC=blu,DC=local",
"givenName": "given name",
"whenChanged": "20170801114732.0Z",
"name": "Accounting",
"mail": "accounting@mail.com",
"updated_at": "2017-07-04T18:22:43.641Z"
 },
   {
    "_id": "590321138",
    "dn": "CN=hallo name,OU=emplyee,OU=Organisation,DC=com,DC=local",
    "sn": "",
    "title": "developer",
    "givenName": "Tina",
    "whenChanged": "20170809073930.0Z",
    "department": "Mobile",
    "company": "Private limited",
    "name": "Full Name",
    "mail": "mail@yahoo.com",
    "mobile": "+123456",
    "updated_at": "2017-04-28T11:01:39.475Z"
  }
]
```

**My Model class is**

```
public class ColleagueModel {


private String id;
private String dn;
private String sn;
private String givenName;
private String whenChanged;
private String name;
private String mail;
private String updatedAt;
private String title;
private String department;
private String company;
private String mobile;

public ColleagueModel(){

}
 public ColleagueModel(){

 }

public ColleagueModel(String name, String company,String title) {
    this.name = name;
    this.company = company;
    this.title = title;

}
```

My Activity class is

```
  public class MyColleaguesPage extends AppCompatActivity implements MyColleaguesAdapter.ColleagueListListener {

// CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and READ_TIMEOUT are in milliseconds
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private MyColleaguesAdapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mycolleagues_layout);

    new AsyncFetch().execute();

}

private class AsyncFetch extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {

            // Enter URL address where your json file resides
            // Even you can make call to php file which returns json data
            url = new URL("https://app.../api/users");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
        try {

            // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            // setDoOutput to true as we recieve data from json file
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return e1.toString();
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            // Check if successful connection made
            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                // Read data sent from server
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                return (result.toString());

            } else {

                return ("unsuccessful");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        //this method will be running on UI thread


        List<ColleagueModel> data=new ArrayList<>();

        try {


            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);


            // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
               JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                ColleagueModel model = new ColleagueModel();
                String val1=json_data.optString("name");
                String val2= json_data.optString("company");
                String val3=json_data.optString("title");
                model = new ColleagueModel(val1,val2,val3);
                data.add(model);
            }

            // Setup and Handover data to recyclerview
            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.colleagues_recycler);
            adapter = new MyColleaguesAdapter(MyColleaguesPage.this, data);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MyColleaguesPage.this));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MyColleaguesPage.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

**Logcat**

```
    08-19 08:22:39.141 1301-1301/? W/SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
08-19 08:22:40.780 1582-2172/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=demo.app.com.bluapp_client_and/.activity.myColleague.MyColleaguesPage} from uid 10164 on display 0
08-19 08:22:40.785 26719-26719/demo.app.com.bluapp_client_and I/System.out: 3
08-19 08:22:40.883 26719-26719/demo.app.com.bluapp_client_and E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
08-19 08:22:40.914 26719-26747/demo.app.com.bluapp_client_and D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa9ba7320: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa9baf6b0)
08-19 08:22:40.948 26719-26747/demo.app.com.bluapp_client_and D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa9ba7320: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa9baf6b0)
08-19 08:22:40.962 26719-26747/demo.app.com.bluapp_client_and D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa9ba7320: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa9baf6b0)
08-19 08:22:40.977 1582-1602/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed demo.app.com.bluapp_client_and/.activity.myColleague.MyColleaguesPage: +192ms
08-19 08:22:40.995 26719-26747/demo.app.com.bluapp_client_and D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa9ba7320: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa9baf6b0)
08-19 08:22:41.026 26719-26747/demo.app.com.bluapp_client_and D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa9ba7320: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa9baf6b0)
08-19 08:22:41.052 26719-26719/demo.app.com.bluapp_client_and D/Error:: org.json.JSONException: Value unsuccessful123 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
08-19 08:22:41.114 26719-26747/demo.app.com.bluapp_client_and D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa9ba7320: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa9baf6b0)
08-19 08:22:41.327 1582-2172/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=demo.app.com.bluapp_client_and/demo.app.com.bluapp_client_and.activity.main.MainOptionPage) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurface:2073 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:363 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.notifyAppStopped:389 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.notifyAppStopped:4456 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.activityStoppedLocked:1252 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.activityStopped:6903
```

Comment: have you tried to print data value in Log?

Comment: @shahid17june yes I tzried to get val1 but , no data is there. I have attached my logcat

Comment: what is the value of `String result` inside `onPostExecute` in logcat

Comment: Log.d("result"+"", String.valueOf(jArray)); I try to do it in this way. But I am not getting any reply here. It direct go to the exception in onPostExecution

Comment: try to print Log.d("result", result); and check

Comment: you are getting unsuccessful123 from your server call which is causing error

Comment: yes. But I cannot identify what is the problem here. Is there any problem in server requset sending

Comment: you are parsing `unsuccessful123` to JsonArray thats why you are getting error

Comment: yes check your server call

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152318/discussion-between-akhilesh-patil-and-tamrezh21).

Answer (score 0):

```
        Replace Your java file like this.



public class MyColleaguesPage extends AppCompatActivity implements MyColleaguesAdapter.ColleagueListListener {

        // CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and READ_TIMEOUT are in milliseconds
        public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
        public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;

        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private MyColleaguesAdapter adapter;
      List<ColleagueModel> data=new ArrayList<>();


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.mycolleagues_layout);
      recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.colleagues_recycler);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MyColleaguesPage.this));
                    adapter = new MyColleaguesAdapter(MyColleaguesPage.this, data);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);



            new AsyncFetch().execute();

        }

        private class AsyncFetch extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
            HttpURLConnection conn;
            URL url = null;
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
                try {

                    // Enter URL address where your json file resides
                    // Even you can make call to php file which returns json data
                    url = new URL("https://app.../api/users");

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return e.toString();
                }
                try {

                    // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                    // setDoOutput to true as we recieve data from json file
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);

                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                    return e1.toString();
                }

                try {

                    int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

                    // Check if successful connection made
                    if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                        // Read data sent from server
                        InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                        String line;

                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            result.append(line);
                        }

                        // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                        return (result.toString());

                    } else {

                        return ("unsuccessful");
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return e.toString();
                } finally {
                    conn.disconnect();
                }

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                //this method will be running on UI thread




         try {


                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);


                    // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
                    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                       JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        ColleagueModel model = new ColleagueModel();
                        String val1=json_data.optString("name");
                        String val2= json_data.optString("company");
                        String val3=json_data.optString("title");
                        model = new ColleagueModel(val1,val2,val3);
                        data.add(model);
                    }

                    // notify recyclerview
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MyColleaguesPage.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: I have tried your code. but it never execute the try in onpostexecution. I am getting a msg from exception that java.lang.string cannot be concerted to java array

Answer (score 0):

**Gson** is best to handle your json string conversion.

Here is your **code**.

```
public class MyColleaguesPage extends AppCompatActivity implements MyColleaguesAdapter.ColleagueListListener {

public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private MyColleaguesAdapter adapter;
private List<ColleagueModel> data = new ArrayList<>();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mycolleagues_layout);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.colleagues_recycler);
    adapter = new MyColleaguesAdapter(MyColleaguesPage.this, data);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MyColleaguesPage.this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    new AsyncFetch().execute();
}

private class AsyncFetch extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            url = new URL("https://app.../api/users");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
        try {
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return e1.toString();
        }

        try {
            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }
                return (result.toString());
            } else {
                return ("unsuccessful");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Type modelList = new TypeToken<List<ColleagueModel>>() {
        }.getType();
        List<ColleagueModel> CollegeagueList = new Gson().fromJson(result, modelList);
        data = CollegeagueList;
        adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
    }
}
}
```

You have to **include Gson library** in your project.

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
```

> If you have more problem in Manual Http connection. You can simply
>   achieve it by retrofit open source library

http://square.github.io/retrofit/

> If you want to know how to implement Retrofit in your project, look at
>   this tutorial.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html

Comment: I just notified that I am not getting any response from server. It is returning  ("unsuccessful"); and go to the exception in on post exceution. is there any mistake iin sending correct request on the server

Comment: See the last line. You can use retrofit to handle network calls

Comment: I have tried this with retrofit. before. Could you please see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45757805/recyclerview-using-retrofit-gson-is-not-populated-with-json-data?noredirect=1#comment78474119_45757805

Answer (score 0):

Use following link for simple explanation of attaching data to recycler view. 
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-recyclerview-and-cardview-tutorial/

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use Volley, everything will be easy

Comment: Previously I try to do it wilh library. But I am very new in android developing. so There are so many things which I cant handle with library